# How can I query multiple columns and only return the values that are selected elsewhere?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I can't embed images yet, but I have included them as inline links.

In Google Sheets, I have built a set list builder for my band.  Currently, I have dropdowns that allow the user to select a song from our song list.  I want these dropdowns to be dynamic, and only allow the user to select songs that [have not already been selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS8jd.png)

[image: have not already been selected.]

Because we usually have 3 sets in a night, I need to query the three "set" columns to see if a specific value has been selected in any of the 3 columns, and only include a song in the list if it hasn't been selected in any columns, to prevent anyone from selecting the same song twice.

I was able to make this work using a [IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP)) function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EXVK.jpg)

[image: IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP)) function]

for a single column, but I can't figure it out for multiple rows in multiple columns.

The current query I am using is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY(TO_TEXT({A:C}),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null")))
```

This formula works for the first column, A (set 1), but not columns B or C (set 2 or 3).

Link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18i3AgDOU4zIqsmZQaaA5HiGOfwLA0BoFB4qBa-Tl1SI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You are creating Set lists based on a list of songs. Up to three Sets are created. The overarching rule is that no song should be played more than once. Therefore the available songs for Sets 2&3 are dependant on the preceding each Set. Your formulae for keeping track of songs in each set and the unplayed songs is not working for Sets 2 & 3.

This answer is not a minor adjustment to a specific formula. There is a flaw in identifying the available songs and the songs chosen for each set.

**Sheet"DO NOT TOUCH" (Available songs)**

The structure of Sheet"DO NOT TOUCH" needs to reflect the songs available and the songs chosen for each Set.

---

[image: Do Not Touch]

---

The formula that apply in this layout are:

- Column A: `=query(SONGS!B3:B,"select *")` (Cell A2). List all the available songs.
- Column B: `=query(SET_1,"select *")` (Cell B2). List the songs selected for Set1.
- Column C: `=filter(Set1Available,len(Set1Available),iserror(match(Set1Available,B2:B,0)))` (Cell C2). Compare i)available songs and ii)songs from Set1; list songs not included in Set1.
- Column D: `=query(SET_2,"select *")` (Cell D2). List the songs selected for Set2.
- Column E: `=filter(Set2Available,len(Set2Available),iserror(match(Set2Available,D2:D,0)))` (Cell E2). Compare i)available songs for Set2 and ii)songs from Set2, list songs not included in Set2.
- Column F: `=query(SET_3,"select *")` (Cell F2). List the songs selected for Set3.
- Column G: `=filter(Set3Available,len(Set3Available),iserror(match(Set3Available,F2:F,0)))` (Cell G2. Compare i)available songs for Set3 and ii)songs from Set3 list songs not included in Set3.

Note: I created named ranges for `Set1Available` ('DO NOT TOUCH'!A2:A62), `Set2Available` ('DO NOT TOUCH'!C2:C62), and `Set3Available` ('DO NOT TOUCH'!E2:E62).

---

**WORKING-SET1/SET2/SET3**

The Data validation for each Set must change; this is the reason that your formula didn't work.
 - SET1: `Set1Available`
 - SET2: `Set2Available`
 - SET3: `Set3Available`

---

**SETS**

[image: SETS]

---

You'll notice in this screencap that "ALIVE" is included in Sets 1 & 3. It was originally added to Set 3 (when it was a valid selection), and later it was added to Set1. The entry in Set3 is now invalid it displays the red invalid data indicator.

FWIW, I also noticed that the "Time Est" formula was not consistent in every row; you may wish to revisit this.

Props: [Compare two lists and return only those values that are missing from one list](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/7345105?hl=en)